# Regular installation or Live USB with Reserved Space?

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I recently just got a another 8 GB flashdrive (I have a total of 3 flashdrives, 18 GB of total usable space) and I want to install Ubuntu and boot it on a computer to do some coding and Robotics (class at high school). But the Live CD only allows 4 GB maximum of reserved space, but I want to fill it all. Should I just install Ubuntu regularly onto that flashdrive, or am I asking a bit much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install onto the flashdrive. But, I recommend creating two partitions on the flashdrive, one holding the Live OS and another one formatted with ext4, holding the data.

You can create an ext4 partition by using Live Ubuntu. Boot to Live Ubuntu and start `gparted` program to create partition.

You may want to first use a smaller flash drive to use to Boot to Live Ubuntu, then when you are on the Live Session, insert the biggest flash drive and create two partition there.

Create first partition around 800MB and use the remaining space for the data partition.